# Redirecting from domain to a wordpress site

Tags: redirect, wordpress, 1and1

Is it possible to configure redirecting from mydomain.com (purchased from 1and1) to a wordpress site that is built/hosted on wordpress? Will I run into search engine/SEO issues if going this route?
Is it advisable? Or should I simply subscribe to 1and1's site hosting service?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you talking about? If you have a WordPress site you can host it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are hosted on wordpress.com, there is a $13 / year charge. See http://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/map-existing-domain/ for the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your domain registrar in this case 1AND1 should have a `domain forwarding` option, within your control panel, that you can use to point it to another domain. Side effects in terms of SEO is insignificant. Domain forwarding to another domain does not add higher ranking.